# Unexpected end tag (HTML ERROR)

Tags: html

I've just started working with html and javascript, and in my index.html file I'm getting an error for the closing head tag and opening body tag. The error says "Unexpected end/start tag (ignored)". As far as I can tell, everything in the html file is opened and closed correctly, and in the right order. Below is a picture of my code for reference.
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuJhF.png)

Comment: No, no, no, NO! Please, do not paste images of text, that's just inconsiderate.Post the actual text in your question!

Comment: Sorry, when I posted the html code it was displaying the output of the html in the editor, I didn't want it to show up weird.

Comment: Ahh okay. Well, just enclose the code in back-ticks (the other character on the ~ key)

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because you've got your h1 tag in your head. Try moving it to the body